# Arduino Serial.print() sending the data with a delay between bytes

Tags: arduino, serial

I'm trying to send some current measured data by Arduino to my main MCU. I used the serial.print() function to do so this is the code I used:

[image]

In receiver side I can get the data correctly but after some random minutes of working the receiver doesn't receive data anymore. I used a logic analyzer to capture the data and I see a timing gap between some data which I guess may cause the problem. What is this gap coming from. I also tried to disable the interrupts while sending data but this didn't help.

[image]

Comment: interrupt is used to send Serial data from TX buffer on some Arduinos

Comment: If the Arduino uses interrupts to transmit, disabling interrupts will stop the transmit until they are enabled. Also if there are other interrupts happening in the background they can take some time and the transmission may have a pause.